# IntelliJ IDEA 15 Scene Builder not showing all controls

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I have troubles with the built in Scene Builder. When used standalone Scene Builder displays everything fine. Did I mess up some settings in IntelliJ Idea or it's a bug.

I use IntelliJ Idea 15.0.3 (64 bit) and Scene Builder 2.0.

One thing I changed in IntelliJ was the heap size. Here is my idea64.exe.vmoptions file:
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow

I increased -Xmx to 2GB because it was complaining that it needs more ram ... hungry java... That's also the reason I switched to 64 bit version. The 32 bit didn't want to boot with more than 1.1GB heap. I noticed that SceneBuilder about dialog sais "Operating System: Windows 7, x86, 6.1". Does it have troubles working with 64 JRE? It's java, it shouldn't matter what's below...

I'll post an update when I try Scene Builder with idea running with 32-bit JRE.

**Update:** IntelliJ with 32 bit JRE acts the same way.

[image: Scene builder built in IntelliJ Idea 15]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use right click on .fxml file, then choose "Open in SceneBuilder" in the bottom of options list. This will open .fxml file in fully-version of Scene Builder application with all the aptitudes.

After doing some changes, just click File->Save in the Scene Builder.

I advice you to create a hotkey combination of "Open in SceneBuilder" option in File->Settings->Keymap.

Comment: Well it seams that it's a bug. open in external application requires remembering to save before build -> not that easy when you get used to the IDE doing everything for you. I'll accept this answer since it's not a matter of settings and there is no other solution. I've abandoned javafx because of compability. I don't want to bundle fx library in order to run my app everywhere.