# JavaFX Scene Builder in Intellij IDEA - font settings are not loading

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I have a problem with interaction of Intellij IDEA 15.0.4 and Scene Builder v.2.

When I'm trying to change the font size of a label or text field / text area, by clicking on corresponding dropdown on the right side of the Builder - list of font [is not appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPHIk.png).

But when I'm trying the same thing in desktop version of Builder - [all works normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFK5M.png).

I'm using the IDEA's darcula theme.

If you have any idea of how to resolve that problem - I'll be glad to see your answer.

Thanks.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35443851/3956070)

Comment: I've found a solution, I described it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35975044/2523590).